# Can I search in the terminal window text?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have just now pull some git changes from remote and its a very long log. I want to look some files in the log.

But there is no option to search in the terminal window.

How can I search like we do in windows, there we have find in right click edit menu ?

Comment: `mate-terminal` has a search tab in menu...

Comment: oops yes very right

Comment: So does `gnome-terminal` (in the global menu, not in the right click one).

Comment: In case you are looking for a more general solution that allows you to get multiple panes/tabs, scrolling and searching in both directions *in any kind of terminal or console* have a look at `byobu`. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Go to:

```
Search -> Find...
```

Or use the shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

You'll see a search mini-window like:

[image]

then this is self-explanatory i believe.

Comment: You can get a screenshot of a single window with `Alt`+`Print Screen`. It will save you the cropping step. :)

Answer (score 3):

While it is possible to do this from gnome-terminal's GUI [as explained by heemayl](https://askubuntu.com/a/841584/91549), a better way is to use the UNIX terminal itself. In general, if some command outputs lots of text that you want to search through, a useful thing is to pipe it to [`less`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)).

```
$ some_verbose_command | less
```

This is a simple pager program which allows you to scroll and search through text.

[image: Demonstration of how to view lengthy stdouts with less]

To search for something within `less`, press <kbd>/</kbd> and enter the text you want (supports [regexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)). To skip to the next matching occurence, press <kbd>n</kbd>. To exit `less`, press <kbd>q</kbd>.

As a matter of fact, at least on my setup, git already shows lengthy reports by default in a less-based pager, so there's not really a need for explicitly piping it to `less`:

[image: Example of how git uses a pager for lengthy output]

If it doesn't do this for you, maybe you need to set

```
$ git config --global core.pager less
```

---

Now, this text-browsing with `less` is still not so different from a scrolling&searching in a GUI. Where the command line really shines though is that you can use dedicated commands to filter the output before it's ever shown on screen. The most standard tool for that is [`grep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep).

```
$ some_verbose_command | grep 'string_you_want'
```

[image: Example display showing how grep can filter the output of git.]

Once again though, you don't actually need the special tool if it's `git` you're talking, because [it already has that kind of functionality built in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468361/search-all-of-git-history-for-a-string).

[image: Showing git grep in action]